# Linker generates LNK2001 (( try to make unmanaged c++ dll in vs 2010

Tags: c++, linker-errors

```
    Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall MPPostProcess::prepareForProcess(void)" (?prepareForProcess@MPPostProcess@@UAEXXZ)   D:\Prj\MagicLib\MagicLib\dllmain.obj    MagicLib
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall MPPostProcess::prepareForProcess(void)" (?prepareForProcess@MPPostProcess@@UAEXXZ)   D:\Prj\MagicLib\MagicLib\MPImageData.obj    MagicLib
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual __thiscall PPBlackAndWhite::~PPBlackAndWhite(void)" (??1PPBlackAndWhite@@EAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void * __thiscall PPBlackAndWhite::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GPPBlackAndWhite@@EAEPAXI@Z)   D:\Prj\MagicLib\MagicLib\dllmain.obj    MagicLib
```

How to cure  this?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 likely candidates for unresolved external errors:

1. If you defined the MPPostProcess class, then you have probably forgot to provide an implementation for the prepareForProcess(void) and ~PPBlackAndWhite(void) functions.
2. If the MPPostProcess class is a class you are using provided by an external library, then you need to link to the library that provides those functions

Comment: 1. no  PPBlackAndWhite:MPPostProcess  and there is virtual prepareForProcess() in MPPostProcess  2. no it is my class

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't provided definitions for `prepareForProcess()` or `~PPBlackAndWhite()`.

Comment: I have provide them. Buy the way there are five more functions with the same signature in my files but linker not generate errors with them/ I am trying to find the difference now(

Comment: You may think you have, but the compiler is telling you that you haven't.  Either you aren't compiling them, or they have the wrong signatures.  Post the code that implements these and their declarations.

Comment: PPBlackAndWhite(); is a void constructor. the class PPBlackAndWhite is a PPBlackAndWhite: public MPPostProcess.

Comment: Please post the actual code by editing your original post -- not by commenting here.

Comment: John! You was right!  THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I have simply tied and I did not see that I have forgot implement this functions/ 12 ty hours working day that is ... sorry for my comments - you was right from the first word)